# How to know save password of any website saved in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, password-management, password-recovery

I logged in to the trello.com website and I saved the password in Chrome when I did so.

Now I want to login on other desktop but I forgot my password. Is there any way to find the password which is already login previous desktop?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Mokubai Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-view-saved-passwords-chrome) - which I found by googling "Chrome view saved passwords".  I have copied the main content of the article below, but updated the screenshots to show how to do this with the latest version of chrome (I'm currently running 62.0.3202.94)

Open your Chrome browser and from the top right Chrome menu button, select Settings. Alternatively, you can simply type chrome://settings in the address bar and hit Enter.
[image]

Scroll down and click on Show advanced settings. 
[image]

Now scroll down to the Passwords and forms section and click on the Manage passwords link.
[image]

You will a list of all your saved passwords. The passwords will be hidden by asterisk marks. To see them, click on the Show link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are signed in to Chrome, just view the password on https://passwords.google.com